# URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am new to webpack and I got the babel loader and css loader to work and project compiles successfully but when I try to access via browser I get the below error. It looks as if PUBLIC_URL is not recognized. I believe I don't know how to configure this.

I appreciate your valuable comments.

Thanks

```
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully. URIError: Failed to decode param 
'/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico' at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>) at 
decode_param (/home/mike/finance- 
grapher/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:172:12) at Layer.match 
(/home/mike/finance- 
grapher/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:123:27) at matchLayer 
(/home/mike/finance- 
grapher/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:574:18) at next 
(/home/mike/finance- 
grapher/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:220:15) at expressInit 
(/home/mike/finance- 
grapher/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5) at Layer.handle 
[as handle_request] (/home/mike/finance- 
grapher/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) at trim_prefix 
(/home/mike/finance- 
grapher/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13) at 
/home/mike/finance-grapher/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7 
at Function.process_params (/home/mike/finance- 
grapher/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

[Webpack.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEGo0.png)

[.babelrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Rne.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQMgA.png)

[project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2zGL.png)

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue? you'd think a basic reactjs, webpack, and babel configuration would be more trivial...

Answer (score 41):

#### Quick fix

What if you were to replace `%PUBLIC_URL%` with the actual path. I think that Babel is having issues transpiling the `%`. Try replacing `%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico` with `/public/favicon.ico` and the issue is resolved.

#### Better fix

Add a new rule to your webpack.config.js.

```
//...
{
  test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'] // ?name=[name].[ext] is only necessary to preserve the original file name
}
//...
```

Then have the .ico resource copied to the **dist** directory by adding an import in your **App.js**. `import '../public/favicon.ico';`

In your index.html; `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">` to make use of your icon. No longer need to provide a path since it will be copied to the **dist** directory

OR:

In addition to the rule added to the **webpack.config.js** mentioned above, adding  plugins to the webpack config may be a better way to go depending on your setup.

For me this looks like adding the npm package [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) to the project. Then requiring it in the webpack config; `const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');`. Then adding `plugins` to the `module.exports`.

```
//...
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './public/index.html',
    filename: './index.html',
    favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
  })
]
//...
```

Going this route and doing the work in the webpack config means the line added to the **App.js** to import  the favicon.ico will no longer be necessary.

---

EDIT: As mentioned by @Tolumide

> Don't forget to configure the *webpack.config* appropriately per environment.

Comment: Remember to do the same thing for development, or production if you're using a different setup for both environments

Comment: I use different configurations per environment; oversight on my part for not including that.  Thanks for mentioning it!  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Using the HtmlWebpackPlugin works. In case you did this and still don't see changes, IT MIGHT BE BECAUSE OF CACHING. Test your favicon with a browser you normally don't use.

Answer (score 5):

**Problem fixed**
step 1)
remove %PUBLIC_URL% with the actual path. `%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ic`o with `favicon.ico`
***Before*** `<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />`
***After*** `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />`

step 2) add this rule to the webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
    favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    filename: "index.html",
    manifest: "./public/manifest.json",
  })]
```

step 3) add svg support in webpack(**important**)
install svg-url-loader package

```
 {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
            },
          },
        ],
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and fixed it with the following:

Inside webpack.config.js in the `plugins` array, add `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and `InterpolateHtmlPlugin`

```
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true,
                },
              }
            : undefined
        )
      ),

      new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw)
```

This is the documentation of `InterpolateHtmlPlugin`

```
Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
In development, this will be an empty string.
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error from **create-react-app** when I was serving the page from express server. It was because I was serving static pages from `public` folder instead of `build` folder.

Not working:

`app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));`

Working

`app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')));`

Answer (score 2):

Installing [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) then import the plugin into ***webpack.config.js*** and add this into plugins section worked for me.

```
plugins: [
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
      favicon: './public/favicon.png'
   }),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution

1. npm install interpolate-html-plugin --save-dev
2. Add to list of plugins in webpack config

`new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({PUBLIC_URL: 'static })`

Comment: Yours is the only one that works for me. I don't have my assets in the static folder because I am not using a CDN at this time so mine reads `new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({PUBLIC_URL: '' })`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.favicon %>" rel="shortcut icon">
```

and

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   favicon: "image/favicon.ico",
})
```

and

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|ico)$/,
  use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]']
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using webpack. Please check the package.json the "homapage" attribute. In dev, it must be `"homepage" : "."`´

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).