# "URIError: Failed to decode param" trying to start express app

Tags: express

I'm working on a portfolio and I uploaded it to GitHub pages,
now when I'm running `npm start` I get this error:

```
    Compiled successfully!

You can now view portfolio in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000//averageleo.github.io/portfolio
  On Your Network:  http://10.0.0.3:3000//averageleo.github.io/portfolio 

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

URIError: Failed to decode param '/averageleo.github.io/portfolio/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png'
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at decode_param (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:172:12)
    at Layer.match (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:123:27)
    at matchLayer (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:574:18)
    at next (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:220:15)
    at expressInit (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7     
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
URIError: Failed to decode param '/averageleo.github.io/portfolio/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json'
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at decode_param (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:172:12)
    at Layer.match (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:123:27)
    at matchLayer (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:574:18)
    at next (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:220:15)
    at expressInit (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7     
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\ariek\Desktop\Projects\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

I would appreciate any help, I can't work on the project without testing.. :(

BTW I checked I'm on the master branch and origin remote.
Thanks

Comment: I corrected the tags as this has nothing to do with any of those. Looking at the stack trace, this is an express app. It doesn't look like you've configured it or coded it correcty. I'm pretty sure you need to supply more detail, though maybe an express expert will be familiar with this error.

Comment: I didn't use express and the app worked perfectly before I deployed it.

Comment: In the stack trace: "node_modules\express".  This is an Express app that you are trying to start.

Comment: You can find the same issue on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824024/urierror-failed-to-decode-param-public-url-favicon-ico